# What are plural expressions in Angular template syntax?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Webstorm offers syntax highlighting options for Angular Templates, and one of those options is called "plural expression".

And as you can see from the screenshot, it has a single set of curly braces, commas have a special meaning, and other weirdness I've seen nowhere else in Angular's template syntax.

What is this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The usage for plural is like this

```
{totalItemCount, plural, =0 {no files} =1 {1 file} other { {{totalItemCount | number}} files } selected
```

So based on `totalItemCount` if it's 0 then output `no files`, if 1 then output `1 file` else number of selected items + `selected`

output will be like

```
no file selected
1 file selected
15 files selected
```

There is a tutorial [here](https://codeburst.io/using-the-plural-pipe-in-angular-2-2bcc67a14030)

Also there is an equivalent with [NgPlural](https://angular.io/api/common/NgPlural)